# What is the purpose of ClassName.this beyond disambiguation?

Tags: java, android, this

I've seen `ClassName.this` used in a lot of Android code on SO and other places online (rather than the simple `this` keyword) to refer to the current instance of a class.  I understand you may decide to preface `this` with the class name in order to remove any ambiguity, but in my experience doing so is often unnecessary as there can really only be one thing `this` refers to -- the current instance of the class the code is executing in.  Is there something else I'm overlooking that would suggest prefacing the `this` keyword with a class name is always the better practice, or are there any situations where it is, in fact, necessary?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To access the instance of the enclosing-class from inside the inner classes or the anonymous classes, you need to use this syntax:

```
EnclosingClass.this.someMethod();
```

- See [Java Tutorial: Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Comment: Can you not do so by omitting `EnclosingClass.this` and simply calling `someMethod()`?

Comment: Not if `someMethod()` exists in the inner class too.

Comment: @EtienneMiret well yes.  But then we digress to the scenario where the prefix is only used to remove ambiguity.  I think CommonsWare raises the point that EnclosingClass.this is the *only* way to refer to the instance of an enclosing class from an inner or anonymous class.

Comment: It's equivalent to self.someMethod() in swift

Answer (score 10):

> there can really only be one thing this refers to.

That is incorrect.

> Is there something else I'm overlooking that would suggest prefacing the this keyword with the class name is always the better practice or are there any situations where it is necessary?

Yes and yes, respectively. In particular, `ClassName.this` is needed from inner classes to get to the outer class instance of `this`.

For example:

```
  myButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {
          startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyOtherActivity.class));
        }
     });
```

Here, using `this` instead of `MyActivity.this` will fail with a compile error, complaining that `Button.OnClickListener` is not a valid first parameter to the `Intent` constructor. `MyActivity.this` returns the `this` that is the `MyActivity` instance that encloses the `Button.OnClickListener` instance.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured this may be the case but I've seen it used beyond referring to an enclosing class from an inner or anonymous class so I felt compelled to query SO.

Comment: @DavidCowden: Sometimes you will see it from code that had been in an inner class, got refactored out of the inner class, but the developer left the class name qualifier on there, as it did not raise a compile error and they didn't elect to remove it. There are probably some developers who like using it just for clarity's sake.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  Also, I would accept both these answers but I can't so I'll throw some extra rep @Eng.Fouad 's way since they have at least one order of magnitude (in base 10) less than you in the rep department (=

Answer (score 0):

I don't have that much repo to put a comment ,so writing it down as an answer.

I think the basic concern of the question was to check if there exists any advantage of using classname.this over 'this' keyword in scenarios where developer already know that there will not be any inner class call.

Of course in case of inner class scenarios ,you have to use classname.this to call its enclosing class. but there can be scenraio that you already know that this particular code won't be called inside any inner class.so why to specify classname.this,instead just use 'this'.

Comment: Well the way I read the answers was that this was the only reason.  So to answer your comment, there is no reason other than to reference shadowed objects. (Unless you're considering code style preferences, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(RedPanel.this);

Usually you'll see code like this inside of an inner class. So say you have a class called RedPanel that subclasses a JPanel, and say inside of this you have an anonymous inner class that implements ActionListener. If you want to refer to the "this" RedPanel object inside of the ActionListener, you can't use just "this" since it refers to the ActionListener not to RedPanel. To get a handle on the RedPanel "this" you'll need to use RedPanel.this.